# Selenium RC css selector with adjacent sibling combinator picks wrong table row

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

Edit:  I made a mistake in the table data that I originally posted with.  Correction's in **bold**.

I'm writing Python for Selenium RC.  In the document below I'm trying to select the table row that contains "United States" and "1", but the selector is always selecting the row that contains "United States" and "**214**" instead.  I think I know why.  Looks like :contains() is matching the "1" in 214 and that row is selected.

This is my selector syntax:

```
self.selenium.click("css=table#filltbl tr td:contains(%s) + td:contains(%s)"%(country, area_code))
```

where country == "United States" and area_code == "1".  It seems that the adjacent sibling combinator is being ignored.

How can I make :contains() match exactly "1" ?

Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
. . .
<table class="wrapper" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="filltbl" class="tfill" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
       <tr class="fill">
         <td>United States</td>
         <td>214</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="fill">
         <td>United States</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
. . .
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the sibling combinator that's being ignored... anyway can you try an XPath locator instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  You're correct.  The sibling combinator is not being ignored.  I made a mistake in the data that I posted and I've corrected the question.  I don't want to use XPath because it's so slow.

Comment: I don't think you can do an exact match with CSS selectors, only with XPath.

Comment: Thanks, again, for the reply.  I abandoned the use of :contains() in this case.  Since XPath is so slow with IE I ended up iterating over the table until I found the matching row and then used the index in a selector like this: `self.selenium.click("css=table#filltbl tr:nth(%d)"%rowNumber)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check [some examples](http://blog.infostretch.com/?p=1101) that can be helpful for creating complex css3 locators

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It's a nice reference.  I solved the problem as I described above.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.